# SharePoint Online and OneDrive Desktop (Window Explorer) - Sync metadata

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

Is it possible to sync random metadata from SharePoint Online to Window Explorer and vice versa?  I am using am example authors here.  In SharePoint Online, it is set to "Will" but I did that manually so that can be ignored.  I tried to delete the file and resync and it us not showing up as "William".  In Window Explorer it won't show us as "Will" and in SharePoint Online it won't show up as "William".  I would like for it to sync.

I attempted the following article below, but not sure if it is the correct route of if this is possible.
https://enterprise-knowledge.com/creating-managed-metadata-column-sharepoint-online/

From Window Explorer:

[image]

From SharePoint online:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that feature is not part of the OneDrive sync client at this time.

Comment: do you know of any software that can possibly do that?  if not, thanks for the response!

Comment: I'm not aware of any, sorry.